# Unity - How to setup multiple host with the same IP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, port, host

I'm creating a multiplayer game on Unity with the new Networking System. I wanted to try with my friends who have the same IP as me. But it seems that only the first one of us that created a room can be joined. Even after relaunching the game, our rooms are inaccessibles except for my first friend.

I use a simple GUI Interface without any approval check or anything:

```
static void StartButtons()
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Host")) NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
    if (GUILayout.Button("Client")) NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
    _net.ConnectAddress = GUILayout.TextField(_net.ConnectAddress, 30);
    _net.ConnectPort = int.Parse(GUILayout.TextField(_net.ConnectPort.ToString(), 30));
    _net.ServerListenPort = _net.ConnectPort;
}
```

Example:
My first friend creates a room with port 7777.
We enter the IPv4 and port 7777, we can all join.
But if anyone else creates a room with port 9999.
Nobody can connect by entering the IPv4 and port 9999.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are meaning by your friends having "the same IP"? Technically, this is not possible without network address translation. Could you further descibe the networking situation you are facing? Are you and your friends on the same LAN?

Comment: Only one machine can have an IP address.  Your game will be on one server and will accept connections from multiple clients.  Each client will have a unique IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'm totally new to the networking system, excuse me if I'm not very clear.
To provide more information:
Right now I'm testing it with my friend, who is on the same LAN as me.
When I did my research "How to connect with an IP", I found a solution telling me to write in cmd "ipconfig" and send my friend the IPv4 so he can connect to me.
But when we type this, we got both the same IPv4, so I thought my connection problem came from that.
It works when my friend gave me the IPv4, I could connect to his room.
But when I tried to create a room, he couldn't connect.

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with you DHCP server (which I wouldn't assume), it is not possible that you have the same private IP address in your LAN. Are you sure you read the output from `ipconfig` correctly?

Comment: Thanks @Sideways, I was misreading the IPv4, one '1' was '2' for me, my bad! So now by using the IPv4 we can connect by being on the same LAN, but what do I need to do if he's on another one? So my game can be both in LAN or WAN?

Comment: Firstly, I suggest that you become familiar with network address translation (NAT), as it is crucial to the understanding of your networking situation. Essentially, your internet router is the bridge between your local network and the internet. The router is the only device in your LAN that has both a private and a public IP address, meaning it can reach both ends. But other devices on the internet cannot reach the devices in your LAN, only your router. Thus, you'll have to tell your router to forward the packets of your game inside your LAN to the PC running the server. See "port forwarding".